# How to change content of a div by clicking a button outside the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Thanks for taking the time to read this post. Hope those who are asking the same question would get their answers too.

I am working on a single page website divided into 8 big divs, so that when you click on the menu bar, it will take you to one of the divs (or "pages).

On one of the divs (or pages), which is the intro section of my website, I'm trying to introduce this effect :http://jsfiddle.net/unbornink/LUKGt/

I have a row of buttons, e.g. "Who we are", "What we do", "How we think"....and I have a div under this row of buttons, where different texts are shown when you click on different buttons.

I tried to follow all the steps suggested by http://jsfiddle.net/unbornink/LUKGt/. Unfortunately, I cannot get the button to fire.

Here is the code of my work:

```
<head>    
<link href="textContainer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">   <------I put these in CSS style sheet.
.textWord_about{
position: absolute;
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 14px;
top: 22px;
left: 29px;
width: 650px;
height: 390px;
text-align: left;
background-image: url(images/slider_bkgd.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
}
.textContainer_about {
position: absolute;
top: 870px;
left: 234px;
width: 727px;
height: 452px;
z-index: 20;
color: rgb(4,4,4);
display: block;
background-image: url(images/slider_bkgd.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
overflow: visible;
}
.links {
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
</head>



<body>
<div id="menu_about">
<a class="link" href="#about" data-link="first">&nbsp;&nbsp; Why We Exist</a> &#8226; <a class="link" href="#about" data-link="second">Who We Are</a> &#8226;
<a class="link" href="#about" data-link="third">What We Do</a> &#8226; 
<a class="link" href="#about" data-link="fourth">How We Think</a> &#8226; 
<a class="link" href="#about" data-link="fifth">Where We Are Going</a>
</div>
<div id="pages_about" class="textContainer_about">
<div class="textWord_about" data-link="first">
 <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
 </div>
<div class="textWord_about" data-link="second">
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
</div>
<div class="textWord_about" data-link="third">
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
</div>
<div class="textWord_about" data-link="fourth">
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
</div>
<div class="textWord_about" data-link="fifth">
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.textword_about').hide();

$('.link').click(function() {
    $('.textword_about').hide();
    $('.textword_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
        width: '200px'
    }, 300);
});​
</script>
```

Please propose a solution! Much APPRECIATED!

---

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is typo in your selector. Change `textword_about` to `textWord_about` [Note the letter `W` in `textWord_about`]

**Fixed Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/LUKGt/5/ (without your stylesheets)

**Code:**

```
$('.textWord_about').hide();

$('.link').click(function() {
    $('.textWord_about').hide();
    $('.textWord_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
        width: '200px'
    }, 300);
});​
```

Comment: Hi Vega,many thanks for your prompt reply. I've made the changes. However, it's still not working...

Comment: @user1735546 No problem, Can you tell us what is not working? Did you try the fixed code link?

Comment: Hi Vegas, I don't know if it has to do with the CSS styles. When I click a button, it just doesn't fire. It doesn't take me to another content. Instead, all the text layers that go with different buttons are visible and they are overlapped. Can you fathom why that this?

Comment: Hi Vegas, after removing my javascript code altogether, and then replacing it with the javascript code you provided, and then repositioning the line <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  right under <link href="textContainer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  (instead of leaving it at somewhere farther apart between the lines of other codes...), it WORKED!!!!!

Not sure still what mistake I made though lol but thanks!!

Comment: Hi Vegas, sorry for bugging you, if you have the time, can you also look at my another question, which is a follow-up on this one. I'm trying to get the div show something even before I click a button. How can I achieve that?

Here is the link to my follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838045/change-div-content-on-clicking-a-button-outside-div-but-set-one-of-the-content

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily have to use JavaScript for this, if your target audience are using browsers that support the `:active` pseudo class.

[Pure CSS Version](http://jsfiddle.net/kqK3A/)

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the suggestion. Can you propose an alternative way to do this? Much appreciated!

Comment: Click "Pure CSS Version" lol, it is a hyperlink to a JSFiddle I created for you

Comment: Oh SORRY I missed that totally. What if I want to create a fade when the content comes in? Also, I don't want the webpage to jump to a lower section when it's clicked (as in the Pure CSS version you kindly created for me). Instead I want the page to stay where it is, but the content is different. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think, main thing you wouldn't have observed or missing is,

```
You are using 'textword_about' instead of 'textWord_about'.
i.e you are using 'textWord_about' in html and 'textword_about' in javascript.
```

Try making them same i.e maintain both same in html and javascript.

Comment: Hi thank you in fact I got the same answer already but it still doesn't work. Wondering if it has to do with the CSS style ...