# Change div content on clicking a button outside div, but set one of the contents as visible before click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hi all thanks so much for reading this post.

I am following up on my earlier question: How to change content of a div by clicking a button outside the div. Now I can successfully change the content by clicking a button.

However, before I click anything, the div where the content is to be shown is completely blank. I don't want it to be blank. Instead I want it to show something before I click anything. In fact I want it to show the content for button one.

How should I achieve that?

Here is the code of my work:

```
<head>    
<link href="textContainer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript"         src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">   <------I put these in CSS style sheet.
.textWord_about{
position: absolute;
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 14px;
top: 22px;
left: 29px;
width: 650px;
height: 390px;
text-align: left;
background-image: url(images/slider_bkgd.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
}
.textContainer_about {
position: absolute;
top: 870px;
left: 234px;
width: 727px;
height: 452px;
z-index: 20;
color: rgb(4,4,4);
display: block;
background-image: url(images/slider_bkgd.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
overflow: visible;
}
.links {
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div id="menu_about">
<a class="link" href="#about" data-link="first">&nbsp;&nbsp; Why We Exist</a> &#8226; <a     class="link" href="#about" data-link="second">Who We Are</a> &#8226;
<a class="link" href="#about" data-link="third">What We Do</a> &#8226; 
<a class="link" href="#about" data-link="fourth">How We Think</a> &#8226; 
<a class="link" href="#about" data-link="fifth">Where We Are Going</a>
</div>
<div id="pages_about" class="textContainer_about">
<div class="textWord_about" data-link="first">
<p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
</div>
<div class="textWord_about" data-link="second">
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
</div>
<div class="textWord_about" data-link="third">
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
</div>
<div class="textWord_about" data-link="fourth">
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
</div>
<div class="textWord_about" data-link="fifth">
  <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.textword_about').hide();

$('.link').click(function() {
    $('.textword_about').hide();
    $('.textword_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
        width: '200px'
    }, 300);
});​
</script>
```

Your help is much appreciated! THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are hiding all the divs on page load with `$('.textword_about').hide();`

You need to show the first one, replace that line with the following

```
$('.textword_about').hide();
$('.textword_about:first-child').show();
```

Comment: or $('.textword_about').not(":first-child").hide();