# How to tie button (with default, hover, active states) to swap div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the fiddle I set up:  http://jsfiddle.net/TECHipster/J7TD3/3/

This is the jQuery I worked up a few revisions ago:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $(".icon-set a").click(function () {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
$(".line-three div").css("display", "none");
$(".line-three div#" + id + "").css("display", "block"); }); $(".line-three div:not(#1)").css("display", "none"); });
```

The 3 'Interchangeable' lines would all appear on load, so I used a .hide class in the CSS instead and have been struggling with the jQuery toggle function, but to no avail.

The functionality goals I've been trying to achieve:

- The 3rd line ("Interchangeable line") has 3 options (see HTML) that I want to swap out when their respective button (circle div) is clicked.
- So basically, first option (left circle), second option (center circle), third (right circle).
- Since the first 'Interchangeable Line' is displayed on page load by default, I wanted its respective button (left circle) to be in it's .active state (see CSS) on page load as well.

Comment: So in shorter words...you want the buttons to change the content of that div?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change content of a div by clicking a button outside the div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824241/how-to-change-content-of-a-div-by-clicking-a-button-outside-the-div)

Comment: $(".line-three div#" + id + "") == $(".line-three div#" + id)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate.  Same general idea, but this is slightly more involved. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J7TD3/18/)**

First to start with some errors I've noticed:

- You cannot use `ID` like your `#1`, `#2`, `#3` multiple times, **ID must be UNIQUE-per-page**
- In your fiddle you forgot to add the jQuery library

If you simplify your HTML removing unneeded ID's and adding smartly classes like:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="text-set">
        <p>Unaffected line</p>
        <p>Unaffected line</p>
    </div>
    <div class="line-three">
        <div><p><span>Interchangeable line 1.</span></p></div>
        <div><p><span>Interchangeable line 2.</span></p></div>
        <div><p><span>Interchangeable line 3.</span></p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-set">
         <a><div class="circle"></div></a>
         <a><div class="circle"></div></a>
         <a><div class="circle"></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

than all you need is:

```
$('.line-three').each(function(){
  $('> div:gt(0)', this).hide();
});
$('.icon-set').each(function(){
    $('a:eq(0) > .circle', this).addClass("active");
});

$(".icon-set a").click(function () {
    var $parent = $(this).closest('.page');
    var $lines = $parent.find('.line-three > div');
    $lines.hide();
    $lines.eq($(this).index()).show();
    $('.circle', this).addClass('active')
        .end().siblings('a').find('.circle').removeClass('active');
});
```

in CSS I removed the `#page-XY` cause not needed and instead:

```
.page {
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
}
```

Comment: First, thanks!  This is incredibly helpful.  It's nice to see the working result and being able to sort through the code to see why and how, versus scrambling to piece bits of information from my (re)search.   The IDs I had on the buttons were relics from a previous iteration where I had the jQuery semi-functional (at that point, I only had one 'page').

Answer (score 0):

I gave your pages "index parse-able" ids:

page-1

Each button as well:

1-1

1-2

...

page-2

2-1

...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".icon-set a").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var indices = id.split("-");
    var pageNumber = indices[0];
    var divNumber = indices[1];
    $("#page-" + pageNumber +" .line-three div").hide();
    var nthChild = $("#page-" + pageNumber +" .line-three div:nth-child(" + divNumber + ")");
    nthChild.show();
});
```

});